# Xcode save html from server to plist

Tags: html, xcode, plist

I have on my server a php code, when its called   mydomain.com/index.php?id=11, it creates PList-format. But I must save this first on my computer via Browser(safari->save page) and must change the suffix from (.html) into (.plist), so all steps are manually. And then it used in Xcode.

How I can download direct this code by calling mydomain.com/index.php?id=11 in Xcode and save as .plist  ??

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the Plist contains an array of objects, are you able to do this?

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mydomain.com/index.php?id=11"];
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:myURL];

//either use the array as it is or save it to file:

NSString *myPath = @"some/path.plist"; 
[myArray writeToFile:myPath atomically:NO];
```

The same approach would work for a dictionary. I don't think that the suffix matters when doing this, but I haven't tried it myself.